# Reading invoice log file using R

Tags: regex, r

I am relatively very new to R and I am trying to work on a text file and extract some information from it. The file is uploaded in link below.

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=6CB94B1103A17EF6!105&authkey=!ADcPJYpyUXRQPzA&ithint=folder%2ctxt

Sample.txt is the actual file that I am working on and it has some test invoice details (2 invoices). For better understanding on the file I have created sample1.txt which explains what the file actually has by just separating using üü delimiter.

What I am trying to extract is the information like Description, Rate, Qty and amount along with the store id. Store id looks like this in the file - HAR0000000202. Store ID is almost at the end of each record. I am trying to extract these details into a data frame.

Sample output that I am expecting is like below:

```
STOREID           Description                    Rate      Qty      Amount
HAR0000000202     LITTLE CHEF FROZEN SPRING ROLL 325.00   2.000    650.00
.
.
DEL0000000047     DETTOL ORIGIN                  60.00    1.000     60.00
```

I have tried various things using grep, sub options in R and thought I needed some help here. Any inputs on how to proceed is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Manjunath

Comment: Actually you don't need regex in order to do that. You simply need to import the file into R. "help(read.csv)" will provide you with information on how to do that.

Comment: "have tried various things" like what ?